# Please include phone-type-formatter.{country}.js lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masking

I am trying to use the phone mark with React, but I am getting the error

> Please include phone-type-formatter.{country}.js lib.

This is how I've attempted:

```
import CleavePhone from "cleave.js/src/addons/phone-type-formatter.i18n"; // and also
import CleavePhone from "cleave.js/dist/addons/cleave-phone.i18n"; // and BOTH
...
<CleavePhone
  name={name}
  value={value}
  className={cx("form-control", className)}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  options={options}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
...
```

I've also tried requiring it, but no matter what I do the error persists.

I  am using `react-react-app` library. How to solve this?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js/blob/master/doc/reactjs-component-usage.md)? And instead of merely saying "I've tried requiring it" please show how you tried to require it, otherwise it is impossible to know what in said requiring is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick look in their [github](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js):

```
import "cleave.js/dist/addons/cleave-phone.your-country-here";
import Cleave from 'cleave.js/react';

...
<Cleave
  name={name}
  value={value}
  className={cx("form-control", className)}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  options={options}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
...
```

Comment: @gamofe please try the country require before the import and as an import statement as well

Comment: @gamofe and btw what is your locale?

Comment: Oh, it worked like this. I read in the docs about using `require` but didn't think about using it this way.